# Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.List] and content type [text/html]

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to call other service from my spring boot application.

**Employee class**

```
public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String gender;
    private String status;
    
    // Constructor, getters & setters
}
```

Below is my **Rest controller** code

```
@GetMapping("/getUsers")
public List<Employee> getUsers() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    String resourceUrl = "http://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users";

    ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl, List.class);

    List<Employee> items = response.getBody();
    return items;
}
```

I tried adding different response type but I always get below error

```
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [interface java.util.List] and content type [text/html]
```

Comment: Did you try this API `http://gorest.co.in/public/v2/users` from Postman? What response are you getting?

Comment: I tried and getting response from postam

Comment: My guess is it is returning response in html format and it is unable to convert it to JSON. Try setting `Accept` header to `application/json` in the request. For that you need to use `restTemplate.exchange()` method. `getForEntity()` won't work.

Comment: I tried changing to exchange(), but I still get same error

Answer (score 0):

Resttemplate no support the response of 'content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]'.
solution:

```
 MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML,
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```